# Allow commenting on edits

Tags: discussion

It'd be nice to discuss edits, for example talking about why an edit might be wrong, or why undo it, or why make future edits, etc.

Comment: You already can.  Editors are `@` pingable in comments on the post they edited.  You also have the instant edit privilege, so we trust that you know what you're doing.